# Riverpod FutureProvider.family stop working after passing additional params

Tags: flutter, dart, riverpod

A simple test widget. FakeApi generates a list of employees.
If the params passed to futureApiProvider2 is empty, list is displayed correctly, if it has any value, list dont want to reload at all, although method itself is called.

I can't find error.

```
  class FakeApiRepo{
    Future<List<Worker>> getData({required String someText})async{
      List<String> names = ["Arkadiusz",
        "Arkady",
        "Arnold",
        ];
      List<String> surnames = [ "Piskorski",
        "Borowy",
        "Kołek",
        ];
      List<int> ages = [12,14,15,16,17,33,44,55,66,77,88,99];
  
      Random rnd = Random();
      int count = rnd.nextInt(20);
      List<Worker> list = [];
  
      for(var i = 0; i < count; i++ ){
        list.add(
          Worker(name: names[rnd.nextInt(names.length)],
              surname: surnames[rnd.nextInt(surnames.length)],
              age: ages[rnd.nextInt(ages.length)], text: someText)
        );
      }
      await Future.delayed(const Duration(seconds: 5));
      print('There you go: ${count}');
      return list;
    }
  }
```

Providers which I use:

```
final fakeApiProvider = Provider<FakeApiRepo>((ref){
  return FakeApiRepo();
});

final futureApiProvider2 = FutureProvider.autoDispose.family<List<Worker>, CustomParams>((ref, params){
  return ref.watch(fakeApiProvider).getData(someText: params.text);
});
```

CustomParams class ( read: https://riverpod.dev/docs/concepts/modifiers/family#parameter-restrictions )

```
class CustomParams extends Equatable{
  const CustomParams({required this.text});
  final String text;

  @override
  List<Object> get props => [text];
}
```

And a simple test widget:

```
        Column(
          children: [
            TextButton(onPressed: (){
              ref.refresh(
                  futureApiProvider2(
                      CustomParams(
                          text: Random().nextInt(100).toString() <---- if I remove this (text will be empty) then list is regenerated
                      )
                  )
              );
            }, child: const Text('UPDATE')),
            data.when(
                data: (positions){
                  return ListView.builder(
                    shrinkWrap: true,
                    itemCount: positions.length,
                    itemBuilder: (context, index){
                      return ListTile(
                        title: Text("${positions[index].name} ${positions[index].surname}"),
                        subtitle: Text("Age: ${positions[index].age} -- ${positions[index].text}"),
                      );
                    },
                  );
                },
                error: (e, st) => const Center(child: Text('Some error'),),
                loading: () => const CircularProgressIndicator()
            )
          ],
        ),
```

Comment: where is code that listening to `futureApiProvider2 `? `final data = ref.watch(bla bla`

Answer (score 0):

The family modifier is not designed to pass data to the Provider, but to dynamically create similar but separate providers that exists simultaneously.

When ever you call the provider with a different variable (like you do because you generate a random variable) you create a new provider.

```
CustomParams(text: Random().nextInt(100).toString())
```

This means you only ever refresh a provider when your random variable results in a previous value.

It would be interesting to know how you watch the provider, as you have to define a family variable for watching as well because you are selecting which provider "of the family" you want to watch.

Now as i am missing some information on your code i can not give you a perfect suggestion how to solve this issue.   
Generally one way to listen to the same provider while passing data to it is by another provider.

You can create a StateProvider holding the query you want to pass to your FutureProvider, the FutureProvider can then listen to the StateProvider via ref.watch und you can edit the StateProvider while you keep watching the same FutureProvider. 
I included a small runnable example, you could paste that in dart pad.
Underneath is further material.

```
import 'package:hooks_riverpod/hooks_riverpod.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

final queryProvider = StateProvider((ref) => 'Init');

final futureProvider = FutureProvider((ref) {
  final query = ref.watch(queryProvider);
  return fetchingMethod(query);
});

Future<String> fetchingMethod(String query) =>
    Future.delayed(const Duration(seconds: 3), () => 'Send: $query');

void main() {
  runApp(ProviderScope(
      child: Consumer(
          builder: (context, ref, child) => MaterialApp(
              home: Scaffold(
                  floatingActionButton: FloatingActionButton(
                      onPressed: () => ref.read(queryProvider.notifier).state =
                          '${ref.read(queryProvider)} 23'),
                  body: Text(ref.watch(futureProvider).map(
                      loading: (_) => 'loading',
                      error: (_) => 'error',
                      data: (data) => data.requireValue)))))));
}
```

Similar but more complex use case from the riverpod docs: [here](https://docs-v2.riverpod.dev/docs/cookbooks/search_as_we_type#usage-example-search-as-we-type-searchbar)

Generally good material about riverpod 2 (because the official docs are not finished yet): [here](https://codewithandrea.com/articles/flutter-state-management-riverpod/)

Comment: Ok, I tried to simulate filters based on an example from the documentation
https://riverpod.dev/docs/concepts/modifiers/family

What solution would you recommend to use to solve the filtering problem?

Comment: I've updated the answer, to be able to help you more i would need more information. But maybe this is all you need, in which case you can mark my answer as correct. :3